# Python: trying to check for a valid phone number

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that accepts a phone number in the format `XXX-XXX-XXXX` and translates any letters in the entry to their corresponding numbers.

Now I have this, and it will allow you to reenter the correct number if its not correct to start, but then it translates the original number entered. how do i fix this?

```
def main():
    phone_number= input('Please enter a phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ')
    validNumber(phone_number)
    translateNumber(phone_number)

def validNumber(phone_number):
for i,c in enumerate(phone_number):
    if i in [3,7]:
        if c != '-':
            phone_number=input('Please enter a valid phone number: ')
        return phone_number
    elif not c.isalnum():
        phone_number=input('Please enter a valid phone number: ')
        return phone_number
return phone_number


def translateNumber(phone_number):
    s=""
    for char in phone_number:
        if char is '1':
            x1='1'
            s= s + x1
        elif char is '-':
            x2='-'
            s= s + x2
        elif char in 'ABCabc':
            x3='2'
            s= s + x3
        elif char in 'DEFdef':
            x4='3'
            s= s + x4
        elif char in 'GHIghi':
            x5='4'
            s= s + x5
        elif char in 'JKLjkl':
            x6='5'
            s= s + x6
        elif char in 'MNOmno':
            x7='6'
            s= s + x7
        elif char in 'PQRSpqrs':
            x8='7'
            s= s + x8
        elif char in 'TUVtuv':
            x9='8'
            s= s + x9
        elif char in 'WXYZwxyz':
            x10='9'
            s= s + x10
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use regular expressions: You can use `isalnum` to check if something is a number or letter.  You can access the `n`th character in a string using `mystr[n]` so, you could try:

```
def validNumber(phone_number):
    if len(phone_number) != 12:
        return False
    for i in range(12):
        if i in [3,7]:
            if phone_number[i] != '-':
                return False
        elif not phone_number[i].isalnum():
            return False
    return True
```

To see what `phone_number[i]` is doing, try this:

```
for i in range(len(phone_number)):
    print i, phone_number[i]
```

Using `enumerate`:

```
def validNumber(phone_number):
    for i,c in enumerate(phone_number):
        if i in [3,7]:
            if c != '-':
                return False
        elif not c.isalnum():
            return False
    return True
```

---

Once you have it working, you should use it later (inside of `main`) like:

```
def main():
    phone_number = '' # an invalid number to initiate while loop
    while not validNumber(phone_number):
        phone_number = input('Please enter a phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ')
    translated_number = translateNumber(phone_number)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate a little more on accessing the nth character? I've never done that before

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my code: `enumerate` returns all the values of `phone_number` but also returns their positional number `i`

Comment: I just added a check for the length

Comment: I followed the enumerate one but the issue I'm having is that even though I enter a new, valid phone number, it still translates the original incorrect phone number

Comment: `validNumber` should just take a phone number and return `True` or `False`.  Don't expect it to do anything related to your `translateNumber` function.  See my edit.

Comment: Okay, so if it returns true or false, how do I get it to prompt for a correct phone number and use that one instead?

Comment: I've added a way of continually asking until the input is in the correct form.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re

def validNumber(phone_nuber):
    pattern = re.compile("^[\dA-Z]{3}-[\dA-Z]{3}-[\dA-Z]{4}$", re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.match(phone_nuber) is not None
```

Comment: Because some people put `-` in their numbers like `00-000-0000`

Answer (score 3):

1. You should use a regex to match the text.
2. the string module has a `translate` function that will replace most of your logic

code example below.  note how i cast everything into lowercase to simplify the regex and translation.

```
import string
import re

RE_phone = re.compile("^[a-z0-9]{3}-[a-z0-9]{3}-[a-z0-9]{4}$")

map_in  = 'abcdefghijklmnprstuvwxyz'
map_out = '222333444555667778889999'
mapped = string.maketrans( map_in , map_out )


def main():
    while True:
        phone_number= raw_input('Please enter a phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ')
        phone_number = phone_number.lower()
        if RE_phone.match(phone_number):
            break
        print "Error. Please try again"
    print translateNumber(phone_number)

def translateNumber(phone_number):
    return phone_number.translate( mapped )

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go for:-

```
def contact_validate(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> print contact_validate("+12345")
True
>>> print contact_validate("75.0")
False
>>> print contact_validate("hello")
False
```

Comment: This is wrong, there are restrictions on phone numbers such as their length and that they can't be negative

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be helpful

```
def checkvalidNumber(phone_number):
        T={"-":0,"+":0,"_":0}
        for i in str(phone_number):
            if i in list(T.keys()):
                if (i=="_" or i=="-") and (T["-"]>=1 or T['_']>=1):
                    return False
                elif i=="+" and T[i]>=1:
                    return False
                else:
                    T[i]+=1
           elif not i.isdigit():
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a fairly pythonic way to do it in my opinion

```
def validNumber(phone_number):
    return all([x.isdigit() for x in phone_number.split("-")])
```

It splits the input at "-", checks that each remaining item is a number and returns a single True or False value.

`all() - returns True if bool(x) is True for all x in iterable`