# BeautifulSoup html parsing

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a local html file containing contacts. The general form of a contact is:

```
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
  <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel"> NAME </div>
  <div class="_3-96 _2let">
    <div class="_3hls"> PHONE NUMBER</div>
    <div class="_3hls">middle_name: MIDDLE NAME </div>
    <div class="_3hls">note: 0</div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="uiGrid _51mz _21op" style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">number_times_contacted</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">contact_id</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">4914</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">starred</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">last_time_contacted</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">1475961803207</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">custom_ringtone</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">in_visible_group</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">send_to_voicemail</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="_51mx">
          <td class="_51m- _2oao">is_user_profile</td>
          <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="_3-94 _2lem">‏٠١‏/٠٩‏/٢٠١٥ ٢:٢٤ م‏</div>
</div>
```

It's not constant. Which means I can have a contact with: multiple phone numbers - no phone number - no extra data (just his name and the date).

I want to extract each contact correctly. All what matters is his name and phone number(s) if exist. How to do that with beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, you have to use a regex, using `re` package to get what you want because you have multiple `div` with only `_3hls` class and no, one, or multiple phone number.

Regex to find number in this exemple come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15258791/2437141)

You can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import re


def validNumber(phone_nuber):
    pattern = re.compile("^[\dA-Z]{3}-[\dA-Z]{3}-[\dA-Z]{4}$", re.IGNORECASE)
    return pattern.match(phone_nuber) is not None

html = """<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
              <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel"> NAME </div>
                  <div class="_3-96 _2let">
                      <div class="_3hls"> PHONE NUMBER</div>
                      <div class="_3hls">middle_name: MIDDLE NAME </div>
                      <div class="_3hls">note: 0</div>
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="uiGrid _51mz _21op" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                          <tbody>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">number_times_contacted</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">31</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">contact_id</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">4914</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">starred</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">last_time_contacted</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">1475961803207</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">custom_ringtone</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">in_visible_group</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">send_to_voicemail</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="_51mx">
                                  <td class="_51m- _2oao">is_user_profile</td>
                                  <td class="_51m- _2piu _23bw _51mw">0</td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="_3-94 _2lem">‏٠١‏/٠٩‏/٢٠١٥ ٢:٢٤ م‏</div>
              </div>"""

contacts = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder'})
for contact in contacts:
    name = contact.find('div', {'class': '_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel'}).text
    phone_numbers = []
    for div in contact.find_all('div', {'class': '_3hls'}):
        # Test here if div.text is a phone number
        # you can use regex, package...
        if validNumber(div.text):
            phone_numbers.append(div.text)

    print(name)
    print(phone_numbers)
```

Comment: That's what I exactly needed. Thank you so much.